# Python + Kivy: обновление TextInput, как реализовать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Делаю менеджер паролей для личного пользования и решил добавить генератор случайного пароля, когда ты нажимаешь на кнопку Сгенерировать Пароль, TextInput с паролем должен автоматически обновляться и принимать в себя сгенерированый пароль. Код [generator.py](https://gist.github.com/golub4ik23/49a95b55c7c36b37a8189fd4581e0678) (основная инфа комментирована):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.config import Config

import string
from random import *

Config.set("graphics", "resizable", "0")
Config.set("graphics", "width", "700")
Config.set("graphics", "height", "800")

print("--------------")

class PasswordManagerApp(App):

  def open(self, args):
    pass

  def generate(self, args):
    self.password = "".join(choice(self.password_string) for x in range(randint(8, 12))) #генерация пароля
    print(self.password)

  def add(self, args):
    pass    


  def build(self):

    self.password_string = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

    self.resource = ""
    self.login = ""
    self.password = ""

    root = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding = 5)

    top = GridLayout(cols = 6, padding = 5, size_hint = [1, .1])

    top.add_widget(Label(text='Ресурс'))
    top.add_widget(TextInput(text=''))
    top.add_widget(Label(text='Логин'))
    top.add_widget(TextInput(text=''))
    top.add_widget(Label(text='Пароль'))
    top.add_widget(TextInput(text=self.password)) #должно автоматически обновляться при нажатии на кнопку сгенерировать пароль

    root.add_widget(top)

    top_func = GridLayout(cols = 6, padding = 5, size_hint = [1, .1])

    top_func.add_widget(Button(text = 'Открыть файл', on_press = self.open))
    top_func.add_widget(Button(text = 'Сгенерировать пароль', on_press = self.generate)) #вот сама кнопка
    top_func.add_widget(Button(text = 'Добавить аккаунт', on_press = self.add))

    root.add_widget(top_func)


    output = TextInput(size_hint = [1, .8])
    root.add_widget(output)

    return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
PasswordManagerApp().run()
```

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: не помещайте метки в заголовок вопроса, если они не являются частью предложения¶ Вопрос должен быть ясен без внешних ресурсов: если хотите код показать, минимальный пример кода должен быть в самом вопросе [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

1. Присвоить виджету переменную

   self.test = TextInput(text='')
   top.add_widget(self.test)
2. прописать в функцию:

   self.test.text = self.password